# Exception when trying to call Console.Clear() after opening a console a second time

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open a console from a winform application from a button click. I'm doing this via the code below.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern Boolean FreeConsole();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userInput = 0;
        AllocConsole();

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine("Select 1 or 2");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);
        } while (userInput != 1 && userInput != 2);

        FreeConsole();
    }
```

The first time the console is opened, it works fine. Attempting to open the console a second time will work fine, but once `Console.Clear();` is called, I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: The handle is invalid.

The same exception will be thrown on `Console.WriteLine();` and `Console.ReadLine();`.
I've tried the proposed solutions from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604014/no-console-output-when-using-allocconsole-and-target-architecture-x86/43492087), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142878/the-console-crashed-when-i-try-to-open-it-twice-in-wpf), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537279/calling-console-writeline-before-allocating-the-console), but I end up with the same "handle is invalid." error on `Console.Clear();`.

**Some additional code I've tried:**

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",
        EntryPoint = "GetStdHandle",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll",
        EntryPoint = "AllocConsole",
        SetLastError = true,
        CharSet = CharSet.Auto,
        CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern int AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern Boolean FreeConsole();


    private const int STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11;
    private const int MY_CODE_PAGE = 437;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userInput = 0;
        AllocConsole();

        IntPtr stdHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        SafeFileHandle safeFileHandle = new SafeFileHandle(stdHandle, true);
        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(safeFileHandle, FileAccess.Write);
        Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(MY_CODE_PAGE);
        StreamWriter standardOutput = new StreamWriter(fileStream, encoding);
        standardOutput.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(standardOutput);
        Stream streamIn = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        TextReader readerIn = new StreamReader(streamIn);
        Console.SetIn(readerIn);

        do
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine("Select 1 or 2");
            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput);
        } while (userInput != 1 && userInput != 2);

        FreeConsole();
    }
```

This seems to be ok for `Console.WriteLine();` and `Console.ReadLine();` but I still can't get around the exception being thrown by `Console.Clear();`. Can anyone tell me if I'm missing something?

Comment: A process can be associated with only one console, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole

Comment: @Tony "A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its current console, then it can call AllocConsole to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console." from your source...

Comment: You arent checking if AllocConsole() was successful

Comment: @BugFinder, how would it not be succesful? I was able to get passed AllocConsole() fine and do Console.WriteLine as well as Console.ReadLine. Both are fine, the Console.Clear() specifically is what is throwing an exception. Despite this I just ran a test and can confirm that it is successful. AllocConsole() returned 1.

Comment: Are you running from within Visual Studio?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Yes sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it is possible to attach/detach to console multiple times. As far as I understand [the code of `private static IntPtr ConsoleInputHandle`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,698be89e72524af3,references) (the same goes for `ConsoleOutputHandle`), the handle is initialized once on first usage, so when you detach the process from console and re-attach it once again the handle is invalid.

So imho it is  not feasible to use `Console` class as you want (nor do I know any live examples of programs working both as console and Win32 app - the most applications I've seen provide two versions of .exe).

If you really need Windows console I guess you can try to provide your own console wrapper above Windows API. If you need only the looks of console you can go with rendering of your own "console-like" window.

Comment: If this were the case, I would expect AllocConsole to fail. Instead, it succeeds and I am able to use Console.WriteLine and Console.ReadLine. If I can use both of those methods, why not Console.Clear()? Does it somehow use a different handle than the handle used by the former two methods?

Comment: @Sudsy1002 as  far [as I see](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,5a089586e22b4062) `WriteLine` uses handle unconditionally (which is strange for me,  it seems unsafe). The `Clear` method checks if the handle is valid (see the link above) and probably this check is the one that throws. I don't know  why it was coded this way.